# Sorting Custom Posts on Archive page with pagination

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, sort

I've got custom taxonomy archive pages with a drop down list that allows users to re-order/sort the posts. It basically waits for the user to select from the drop down then uses `array_merge( $wp_query->query.....` to create a new query and re-sort the posts. This works fine.  I also use wp-pagination to display numbered pagination.  This also works fine.

The problem is, when a user re-sorts the list, and then clicks on the pagination to go to page 2 the new sort is lost and reverts back to the original.  I can't work this out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I was using a form to sort the data, and a pagination using [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). My solution was to use `$_SESSIONS` to store the `$_POST` data from the sort (instead of just parsing the `$_POST` data), and set the form action to `get_permalink()`. Make sure to unset your session if you are not using pagination or if you are not `$_POST` ing the sort form.

```
<script>
function submitform(val) {
    document.getElementById('sort-option').value = val;
    document.getElementById('form-sort').submit();
}
</script>

<form id="form-sort" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>Sort By:</li>
        <li><a href="#!" onclick="javascript: submitform('newest');">Newest rating</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!" onclick="javascript: submitform('highest');">Highest rating</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!" onclick="javascript: submitform('lowest');">Lowest rating</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type='hidden' id='sort-option' name='sort-option' value=''>
</form>
```

-

```
if($wp_query->get('page') == 0 && empty($_POST) && !empty($_SESSION)) session_unset();

if(!empty($_POST) || !empty($_SESSION)) {

    switch($_POST['sort-option']) {
        case 'newest':
            $_SESSION["sort"] = SORT_DESC;
            $_SESSION["sort_by"] = 'review_date';
            break;
        case 'highest':
            $_SESSION["sort"] = SORT_DESC;
            $_SESSION["sort_by"] = 'rating';
            break;
        case 'lowest':
            $_SESSION["sort"] = SORT_ASC;
            $_SESSION["sort_by"] = 'rating';
            break;
    }

    foreach($reviews as $k => $v) {
        $column_id[$k] = $v[$_SESSION["sort_by"]];
    }

    array_multisort($column_id, $_SESSION["sort"], SORT_NUMERIC, $reviews);

}
```

If you show some code, I might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I ended up paying someone to fix it for me.